# Error python dedupe : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

i have a problem on my python script.

i tried to use an exemple for mysql server (https://dedupeio.github.io/dedupe-examples/docs/mysql_example.html) but i don't have json_object function on mssql (old version).

my python code :

```
def record_pairs(result_set):

objects_listd = []
objects_liste = []

for i, row in enumerate(result_set):
    a_record_id, a_Rue, a_Nom, a_Email, a_TEL, a_SIRET, b_record_id, b_Rue, b_Nom, b_Email, b_TEL, b_SIRET = row
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    e = collections.OrderedDict()

    d['Rue'] = a_Rue
    d['nom'] = a_Nom
    d['Email'] = a_Email
    d['TEL'] = a_TEL
    d['SIRET'] = a_SIRET

    e['Rue'] = b_Rue
    e['nom'] = b_Nom
    e['Email'] = b_Email
    e['TEL'] = b_TEL
    e['SIRET'] = b_SIRET

    objects_listd.append(d)
    objects_liste.append(e)

    jd = json.dumps(objects_listd)
    je = json.dumps(objects_liste)

    record_a = (a_record_id, json.loads(jd))
    print(record_a)

    record_b = (b_record_id, json.loads(je))
    print(record_b)

    yield record_a, record_b

    # if i % 10000 == 0:
    #     print(i)
    break

with cursor as read_cur:
    read_cur.execute("""select 
    CAST(a.[Code Client] AS INT),
    a.Rue,
    a.nom,
    a.Email,
        REPLACE(COALESCE(CASE WHEN RTRIM(a.[Mobile Perso]) = '' or RTRIM(a.[Mobile Perso]) = '0'
            THEN null
            else a.[Mobile Perso]
            END,a.[Fixe Perso],NULL),' ','') as TEL,
    a.SIRET,

    CAST(b.[Code Client] AS INT),
    b.Rue,
    b.nom,
    b.Email,
        REPLACE(COALESCE(CASE WHEN RTRIM(b.[Mobile Perso]) = '' or RTRIM(b.[Mobile Perso]) = '0'
            THEN null
            else b.[Mobile Perso]
            END,b.[Fixe Perso],NULL),' ','') as TEL,
    b.SIRET
    from (select DISTINCT l.client_id as east, r.client_id as west
        from blocking_map as l
        INNER JOIN blocking_map as r on r.[block_key] = l.[block_key]
        where l.client_id < r.client_id) ids
    INNER JOIN Client a on ids.east=a.[Code Client]
    INNER JOIN Client b on ids.west=b.[Code Client]""")

    # ## Clustering
    print('clustering...')
    #clustered_dupes = deduper.cluster(deduper.score(record_pairs(j)),
    clustered_dupes = deduper.cluster(deduper.score(record_pairs(read_cur)),
                                      threshold=0.5)
```

this error :

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dedupe/core.py", line 80, in __call__
    self.fieldDistance(record_pairs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dedupe/core.py", line 91, in fieldDistance
    distances = self.data_model.distances(records)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dedupe/datamodel.py", line 98, in distances
    if record_1[field] is not None and record_2[field] is not None:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/client/msql2.py", line 286, in <module>
    clustered_dupes = deduper.cluster(deduper.score(record_pairs(read_cur)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dedupe/api.py", line 109, in score
    matches = core.scoreDuplicates(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dedupe/core.py", line 170, in scoreDuplicates
    raise ChildProcessError from exc
ChildProcessError
```

my result have a form :

```
(10430, [{'Rue': 'ROUTE DE Nantes X', 'nom': 'DOIGT', 'Email': None, 'TEL': None, 'SIRET': None}])
(15252, [{'Rue': 'RUE FAT X', 'nom': 'CLOPI', 'Email': None, 'TEL': '227868', 'SIRET': None}])
```

and i think he must have this form :

```
[
((1, {'name' : 'Pat', 'address' : '123 Main'}),2, {'name' : 'Pat', 'address' : '123 Main'})),
((1, {'name' : 'Pat', 'address' : '123 Main'}),3, {'name' : 'Sam', 'address' : '123 Main'}))
]
```

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Could you add an example of `read_cur` value, that is passed into ` record_pairs` function?

Comment: ty for your help.
yes of course :
print(read_cur)
(10430, 'ROUTE DE Nantes X', 'DOIGT', None, None, None, 15252, 'RUE FAT X', 'CLOPI', None, '227868', None)